# Indexes in Django after running syncdb

Tags: mysql, django, indexing

Is it there a way to know the current status of mySQL tables in Django after creation through `syncdb` or do I need to use `dbshell`?

Another quick question: Suppose I add an index manually after running `syncdb`, do I have to add `index_db` to the corresponding field in the model?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to. `index_db` only tells django to add an index when creating the table. adding it subsequently has no effect (though you may want to add it anyway to indicate the presence of and index). if you are using [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) (you should be) then adding `index_db`  will add index creation to your next migration.

Comment: Great. I have heard about south but as I'm just learning the basics of Django, so I didn't want to add an extra something too quickly. I read a bit about migrations via http://code.google.com/p/dmigrations/. South is better than dmigrations?

Comment: looks like the last update to dmigrations was in 2008... i'd stick with south

Comment: Alright. I just read south doesn't play well with Django non-rel. Is it there something for Google App Engine?